# Since June 1st, I cannot update ubuntu 11.04 or install anything for the Software Center

Tags: 11.04, software-center

I would like to ask if the software center files regarding Natty Narwhal has been taken offline permanently since June this year?

Practically this means, I cannot install new software from the Software Center.

Now I am pretty happy with my system the way it is, and could live for a time without installing new stuff, but isn't it kind of radical to pull the plug on the Software Center software for Natty Narwhal, just because it isn't supported with updates from Canonical anymore?

Is there a mirrorsite somewhere that still has the Software Center files in that case?

Kind regards,

Comment: Let me pinpoint further, that what I meant with this question, is that I can go into the software center, but cannot update or download/install anything there anymore.

Comment: Yes, 11.04 reached end of life when 12.10 came out; you need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks very much! :-) I went to the above link and found info how to use the old-releases repository and now everything is working nicely again.

Comment: Do be sure to upgrade, not just continue to run/install unsupported software as you are no longer getting security fixes.  If you don't want to upgrade every 6 months then stick to an LTS release ( 12.04 ), which is supported for 5 years.